# Check scrollTop on touch device

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I have the following function that checks the scrolling position of a user so that the menu becomes fixed once they scroll past the masthead

```
function checkScrolling() {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('.masthead').height() ) { // we check against ACTUAL height
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    }else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
}
```

and here the desktop and touch screen event listeners:

```
$(document).bind('touchstart touchend touchcancel touchleave touchmove', function(e){
    checkScrolling();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkScrolling();
});
```

However the touch events only make the menu fixed during the touchmove reliably. If I scroll really fast with a swipe up or down, there is a delay before the menu becomes fixed or unfixed.

Any ideas on how to fix this? **See a code example here: http://dev.driz.co.uk/mobileMasthead.html (has been amended based on some answers below, but still does not work correctly on an iPad or iPhone)**

*Update:*
And reading up on the topic reveals that JS like checking scroll position don't happen during the scroll... **BUT... I've noticed that http://www.facebook.com/home/ doesn't have this issue** when testing it on my iPad. So it's definitely possible to achieve this effect without using any custom JavaScript scrollbars like iScroll or similar.

Comment: Why are you using the touch events other than `touchmove`? I would assume that `touchmove` and `onScroll` would cover the scenarios when you'd need to check for the sticky nav. And do you get different results if you try `$('body').bind()` or `$(window).bind()` instead of `$(document).bind()` for the touch events? I've used `touchmove` while targeting smaller parts of a page and had no lag in returning information.

Comment: There is no lag for either touchmove or scroll. The issue is that the scrollTop value doesn't changed because it doesn't acknowledge the user has moved position until after. Same happens no matter what I bind to.

Comment: Make sure that JavaScript is still running while scrolling. I've had a similar issue in the (Android 2.x) past. The scroll events only got captured when I stopped scrolling. Not sure if it's all supported these days.

Just add a HTML element that gets updated with the time in ms all the time and double check that JavaScript itself is running. It differs per OS/browser.

Comment: Maybe I am not clear on your objective, but have you considered simply making the masthead position fixed to begin with and allowing content to scroll underneath in another DIV element? Or, when you do a scrollcheck, fix its position until the user stops scrolling?  Just a couple of thought...

Comment: If you're looking for performance, drop jQuery. All this can be easily done with vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe I understand the question wrong, but to ensure functionality with high speed scrolling, why don't you tackle it the pure CSS way (aka faking the 'fancy' effect):

### Old School (fast but primitive)

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu2"></div>
    <div class="scroll" id="scroller">
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <div id="menu"></div>
    </div>
```

With the simple CSS:

```
html, body { overflow: hidden; height: 100% }
body { margin:0; padding:0; }

 .scroll {
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
     height:960px;
     width:640px;
 }

 #menu2 {
     width:640px;
     height:20px;
     background:red;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:-1;
 }

 #menu {
     width:100%;
     height:20px;
     background:red;
     z-index:0;
 }
```

You can see a working example [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NKDtR/16/embedded/result/).

It may be a bit primitive: but hey! It works! :)

### New School (fancy but slow)

Check all of the other answers supplied.

But note that it 'is known' that the usage of JavaScript in combination with scrolling on mobile devices is causing a lot of trouble regarding speed.

That's why I think the simple CSS approach may be better.

If you want to learn about JavaScript and scrolling on mobile devices (and other functions), then there are two articles which I highly recommend reading:

- [Fast animations with iOS Webkit](http://joehewitt.com/2011/10/05/fast-animation-with-ios-webkit)
- [Native scrolling: Grins and Gotchas](http://cantina.co/2012/03/06/ios-5-native-scrolling-grins-and-gothcas/)

Comment: Tested it on iPhone but I'm very sure it will work fine on iPad as well since it's just some CSS.

Answer (score 5):

Facebook doesn't use JavaScript but pure css:

```
position: -webkit-sticky;
```

If i remember it correctly this makes the element stick at the top of its parent container when scrolled.

Comment: My browser doesn't support that CSS (Latest Chrome) and yet the Facebook website works. So I'd presume they are using both JS and CSS? Also how would it solve my problem? As I'd still need to apply the sticky if a user scrolled past the masthead which could have varying heights depending on its content. Thanks.

Comment: @Cameron of course they use JS for browsers without support :) the parent of your menu is body, so it would always stick at to top of the page, no matter how far one scrolls. And that's exactly what your script does.

Comment: @Cameron I just checked the source of your page. There is no need for a `sticky` class. Just add the styles to the regular class and let the browser decide ;) That way you don't need `Modernizr.csspositionsticky` either. You can check out [my example](http://www.zeroflagl.com/masthead/)

Answer (score 2):

You just needed to attach your scroll events, not to window, document or body, but to a custom container.

On iOS you can't programatically react during these hardware-accelerated window scrolling behaviour.

Here's a fiddle:
a wrapper:

```
<div id="content">
```

some not-so-relevant css:

```
html,body,#content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#content {
    background-color: lightblue;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

attaching the listeners to the container:

```
function checkScrolling() {
    if ($('#content').scrollTop() > mastheadHeight) {
        menu.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        menu.removeClass('fixed');
    }
}

$('#content').scroll(function () {
    checkScrolling();
});
```

You can see it working here for the JS-only fallback:

http://jsfiddle.net/jaibuu/YqPzS/

direct URL: http://fiddle.jshell.net/jaibuu/YqPzS/show/

Comment: The thing is the jquery scroll event does only fire only on touch devices when the browser has finished flexible scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

I once tried to implement sticky headers on mobile version of a site but had encountered whole set of problems.

First and most important is that `scroll` event does not fire on mobile devices as often as it does on desktop. Usually it does fire when page stops. I don't know the exact reason for that but I can suggest it's because browsers on mobile "send" such tasks to GPU meantime CPU can not keep JS objects up to date with what happens to the canvas (but that's just my suggestion). Newer version of iOSes are making it better for us and probably `scroll` will work on iPhones.

You should use `touch` events. This makes you write a separate version of code for devices that support touch input. So have to look for reliable ways of testing for platform.

But `touch` events are also tricky especially on Android. I thought that in the callback for `touchmove` event I will be able to figure out current coordinates and go further from that point.

But There this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5491 on Android, in summary `touchmove` fires once or twice at the very beginning of the touch action and does not fire again. Which makes it totally useless. People are suggesting preventDefault() but you no longer can scroll with that.

So I ended up with idea to reimplement scrolling from scratch using CSS transforms. And here is my results so far:

http://jsbin.com/elaker/23

Open that link on your device and http://jsbin.com/elaker/23/edit on your desktop: you'll be able to edit code and it will live update on you device, very convenient.

**NOTE:**
I'd like to warn you that this CSS scrolling thing is raw and there are some known problems that are not resolved yet: like you can sometimes scroll beyond top or bottom boundaries or if you just touch (not move) it still will scroll. Also the notorious URL bar will not hide. So there is work to do.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the touch events to fire this at all? Modern devices should return `$(window).scroll()` events and `scrollTop` values. On older Android and and pre-ios5 (I think), `position:fixed:` didn't work as expected because the of how the viewport worked. But it has been corrected in all new releases.

To further debug devices, I highly recommend Adobe Edge Inspect. You could `console.log` the scrollTop and see if the devices you care about actually work correctly with out any trickery. You'll get everything you need with their free version.

Comment: The issue is that the scrollTop value doesn't change until AFTER the scrolling has stopped. Somehow Facebook.com/home has got around this issue without using a custom scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

A great way to dealing with scroll events is not to attach your checks to the scroll event
takes a lot of resources and doesn't work very well with older browsers.
fortunately  you can have a lot more control if you just perform a time loop to do that.
codewise that looks like that:
(It's used by twitter)

```
var MyMenu = $('#menu'),
    didScroll = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if ( didScroll ) {
        didScroll = false;
        //Do your check here
        checkScrolling();
    }
}, 180);
```

You should put your $('.masthead').height() outside this checkScrolling function of yours (in a higher scope) as this kind of operations takes a lot of resources and always ask jquery to "select your element" and calculate its size will eventually make your application laggy:

```
  var headerHeight = $('.masthead').height()
  function checkScrolling()
  .....
```

Last thing , you can change the value of the interval attribute (right now it's 180 (a bit more that 60hz -. refresh time of the screen) you can make this value bigger, if you want your app to be more performant but a bit less accurate)

Thanks John Resig and twitter:
http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Hope that helped
Ajios !

Comment: Tried it here: http://dev.driz.co.uk/mobileMasthead.html and if you test on an iPad or iPhone then you will see that the menu only fixes or unfixes ONCE you've stopped scrolling. So seems that using setInterval hasn't done anything different.

Answer (score 1):

```
setScrollTop: function(inTop) {
    var top = Math.max(0,inTop);

    if (wm.isMobile) { // should always be true for touch events 
        top = Math.min(top, this.listNode.clientHeight - this.listNodeWrapper.clientHeight);

        if (dojo.isWebKit) {
            this.listNode.style.WebkitTransform = "translate(0,-" + top + "px)";
        } else if (dojo.isMoz) {
            this.listNode.style.MozTransform = "translate(0,-" + top + "px)";
        } else if (dojo.isOpera) {
            this.listNode.style.OTransform = "translate(0,-" + top + "px)";
        } else if (dojo.isIE) {
            this.listNode.style.MsTransform = "translate(0,-" + top + "px)";
        }
        this.listNode.style.transform = "translate(0,-" + top + "px)";
        this._scrollTop = top;
        this._onScroll();
    } else {
        this.listNode.scrollTop = top + "px";
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested your functions for efficiency. You should try this

```
function checkScrolling() {         
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > mastheadHeight )menu.css('position','fixed');
    else menu.css('position','');
}
```

This will reduce function call of addClass and RemoveClass and your execution time will take effect. If you want to reduce more execution time, then better to use pure JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var p = $("#stop").offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(p<$(window).scrollTop()){
            console.log("div reached");
            $("#stop").css({position:"fixed",top:0});
        }
        else{
            console.log("div out");
            $("#stop").css({position:"static"});
        }

    })
});
```

I think this will help you.

The total code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TURmt/1/) in jsfiddle.net.

I have tested it for **ipad using safari of online ipad2 simulator** in http://alexw.me/ipad2/ and it has worked there. So, I think it will work on real ipad too.